# Vue 3 SSG with client-side rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, client-side, static-site-generation

A simple question. Is this possible with Vue 3 (and Vite preferably)?

Suppose we have  4 pages:

- Home (/)
- About (/about)
- Pricing (/pricing)
- Contact (/contact)

Is it possible, to prerender each one of these pages so if any one of them is accessed by a user/a crawler a HTML document is quickly returned, but along with a Vue 3 app that hydrates the current page and goes on working like any regular client-side app? So we can keep a highly dynamic UI with page transitions?

Essentially what I'm asking is, is it possible for all of the pages to serve as an entry point, not just `index.html`?

I tried looking into solutions like Nuxt.js's Universal rendering, however, I don't think it could be configured to work this way.

Comment: Have you tried out Vite-ssg plugin?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes I have tried it, unfortunately, there's a lot of issues and not enough documentation, certain features are missing completely, and most importantly - the project was abandoned by the original author (Anthony Fu) in favor of Nuxt...